# flask mail not working on Google app engine

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I use the flask-mail extension to send a signup confirmation mail upon form submission. It works perfectly on the Google app engine development server suggesting I have the smtp settings of the sender email account etc. correct.

However, when I tested the signup page after uploading the tested code to App Engine, I get an internal server error upon form submission when on the development server there was none. Note that I'm using flask mail for mail send and not Google's Mail python API.

Any thoughts? I can upload relevant code if required.

Comment: What do you see in the logs for your Internal Server Error?  Is the sender an allowed address?

Comment: Good call, I checked the log to find this error "The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console." I assume the smtplib in flask-mail uses the socket API? Is there a way to bypass the socket call and get mail working? I'm only doing this for a class exercise and was hoping to dwell in the free version of app engine if possible.

Comment: I'm looking to implement the same thing. Did you get this to work? Or is it unsupported by GAE (I'm using GAE standard environment)?

Comment: follow-up ... same issue. Did you find a solution?